# Specified EMAIL_FILE_PATH and render_to_string

Tags: python, django

I've specified my `EMAIL_FILE_PATH` in `settings.py`, and made a view containing following:

```
message = render_to_string('activation-mail.html', {
            ***more irrelevant code***
        })
```

But when I then execute the function, I get the error that `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: activation-mail.html`

The path for my mails are from `settings.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
CONTENT_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'content')

EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(CONTENT_DIR, 'tmp/emails')
```

The path to my mail template is `content/tmp/emails/activation-mail.html`

Where did I mess up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMAIL_FILE_PATH does not hold value of template directory, it is used only in email file backend as place in which emails are written as files according to [email backend documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#file-backend)

For templates you should set TEMPLATES configuration according to [templates documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#configuration)

Comment: That was it! Looked for a solution where Emails didn't go to templates, but after moving the folder it actually worked out. Thanks